# Accesiing local variables globally in r

Tags: r, scope, igraph

I want to access the variable which i declared in function and using it in for loop globally.. In my example i want to access to variables r anr1 globally outside for loop those are declared in function `val` and `val_all`. Here it will only give the r's value for last 10th iteration.
Can any one help..??

```
g <- graph.ring(10)
V(g)$name <- LETTERS[1:10]
LETTERS[1:10]
val=function(g,i,j)
{
  r=get.shortest.paths(g, i,j ,mode = "out")
  return(r)
}

val_all=function(r)
{
  r1 <- V(g)[r$vpath[[1]]]
  return(r1)
}
for (i in 1:10) 
{
  for(j in 2:10)
  {     
    r=val(g ,i,j)
    print(r[[1]]) 
    r1 = val_all(r)
    print(r1)
  }
}
print(r[[1]])
```

Comment: You should tell us what library you are using for `graph.ring()` etc., to make your code an MWE.

Comment: Hi i am using igraph library in r.

Comment: At the beginning of r script i need to attach one line library(igraph)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use the function and start from all vertices?

```
r <- get.shortest.paths(g, from=V(g))
```

Then you will have all of the information in `r$vpath[[1]]`, `r$vpath[[2]]`, etc.

---

EDIT: I think that only gives you the first vertex's paths. You can try the following:

```
r <- vector('list', length=10)
for (i in 1:10) {
  r[[i]] <- shortest_paths(g, from=i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to store the results of each iteration in a list:

```
loop_results <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
  loop_results[i] <- list(NULL)
  for(j in 2:10) {     
    r=val(g ,i,j)
    print(r[[1]]) 
    r1 = val_all(r)
    print(r1)
    loop_results[[i]][[j]] <- list(r=r, r1=r1)
  }
}
# To access the results, now we use loop_results[[i]][[j]][["r"]] for 
# each iteration i and j
print(loop_results[[1]][[2]][["r"]])
```

Comment: Hi, Scott Thank you for the response. I tried in this way before. Just tried the way you suggested but its not working. And here the class of variable r is list and class of r1 is igraph.vs.

Comment: `loop_results[[1]][[2]][["r"]]` should give you the r list, and `loop_results[[1]][[2]][["r1"]]` should be the igraph object.

Comment: Its giving an error Subscript out of bound and replacement has length zero in R.

Comment: And i want to access whole resultant list of r in global environment outside the loop. Please provide any help.

Comment: Hi @seemaaswani I've fixed the list structure so that it should now build correctly. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add double "<<" to store in the parent environment (in your case, what you see as "Global").

```
variable_in_function<<-"stored outside"
```